# XSLT Count nodes based on a condition until another condition is met

Tags: xml, xslt, count, conditional-statements

This is a skeleton of the type of XML files I am working on.

```
<A type="actor"></A>
<A type="director"></A>
<A type="director"></A>
<A type="producer"></A>
<A type="director"></A>
<A type="actor"></A>
```

Now, suppose that I am on the last node and I want to get a count of the occurences of preceding  until it hits the previous 
ie the number of directors between two actors. Once it hits the previous actor, counting must stop. Not sure how to proceed.

Thank you.

Comment: A sample of your XSLT would be great.

Comment: Reconstructing the XSLT to match the skeleton:
<xsl:variable name="Counter">
      <xsl:value-of select="count(preceding-sibling::A/@type='director')">
</xsl:variable>

Now, this will count all the preceding occurences of type="director". How do I make it stop counting when it encounters type="actor"?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you edit your code into the question so it is well formated and easy to read?

Comment: It is really essential that you show us the following: An XML input (which is _well-formed_), an XSLT stylesheet (which is _complete_) and the output you expect. Then the chances are better your question gets a good answer.

Comment: Ok :(
The reason I did not provide actual input/stylesheet is because both the code and XML data are confidential(I am at work). It is as good as leaking data. 
Is there any way to get a barebones solution? I could then reconstruct it to fit my input. Thank you.

Comment: @Chaitanyabangera, we understand that, we are from same field too :) You SHOULD NOT provide the actual data.. rather provide a SAMPLE data with dummy nodes.. Say `<A><B><C><D>` and no need to provide complete realtime XSLT code, replace those actual nodes by `<A><B><C><D>` again!